# PHP Regex to remove links in brackets?

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for the regex for PHP that will remove all URLs in Parenthesis. So before:

```
hello (http://www.google.com) bla (hello) (https://www.google.com) bla bla (http://www.somewhere.com/wherever/?p=343) bla bla bla (https://www.dldld.com/hfk/f/fd?d=3&t=4)
```

Should give me the following afterwards:

```
hello  bla (hello) bla bla  bla bla bla
```

How would I do that?

I found this for the brackets only:

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $str));
```

Comment: Try this: `\(https?:\/\/.*?\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$subject='hello (http://www.google.com) bla (hello) (https://www.google.com) bla bla (http://www.somewhere.com/wherever/?p=343) bla bla bla (https://www.dldld.com/hfk/f/fd?d=3&t=4)';
$result = preg_replace('%\s*\(https?:\/{2}[^)]*\)%im', '', $subject);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

specify about the content in the paranthesis as well

```
\s*\(https?:\/\/www\.[^)]*\)
```

from the example string, the links start with `http://www` followed by something till the next closing bracket `)`

example : http://regex101.com/r/fE8eS0/1

Comment: There are links which do not have `www` .

Comment: the answer is in accordance with the example not  question , *PHP Regex to remove **links** in brackets*